# No matching function call Strange error

Tags: c++, template-classes

```
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    const int size=4;

    template<class datatype>
    class vector
     {

        datatype *v;

        public:
            vector()
            {

                v=new datatype[size];
                for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
                    {
                        v[i]=0;//initilaizing vector
                    }
            }
            vector(datatype *ptr)
            {
                //v=ptr;
                for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
                {
                    v[i]=ptr[i];
                }
            }

            datatype operator*(vector &obj)
            {
                datatype sum=0;
                for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
                    {
                        sum+=(this)->v[i] * obj.v[i];

                    }
                    return sum;
            }
};

     int main()
    {
        int x[4]={1,2,9,11};
        int y[4]={4,7,7,4};

        vector<int> v1;
        v1(x);//no matching call
        vector<int> v2;
        v2(y);//no matching call
       // v1(x);
       // v2(y);
         int total=v1*v2;
         cout<<"Total of v1*v2="<<total<<endl;
    }
```

> > the constructor which in which i am passing integer array x an y is giving me following error.
> >     error: no match for call to '(vector) (int [4])'.
> >     error: no match for call to (vector) (int [4]).there is some problem with assigning array to pointer.
> >     can anyone correct my code .

Answer (score 1):

In your code:

```
    vector<int> v1;
    v1(x);//no matching call
    ^^^^^^
```

is a function call, but you dont have function of name v1, also your vector does not overload operator(). You probably wanted:

```
    vector<int> v1(x);
```

Also, you need:

```
v=new datatype[size];
```

at the begining of your `vector(datatype *ptr)` constructor.

Comment: I tried vector<int> v1(x); this gives me no such error but console window closes.

Comment: @user5501265 see my edit, there are lots of other problems with your code but I understand you are learning C++.

Comment: Thanks for uderstanding me Marcin.  I added this vect(datatype *ptr):vect() .    i changed my class name to vect and its working now.